# How to capture the value of export and place it inside my program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal, pipe

I apologize if im not using the right terms because this is sort of new to me.

I have a file called utils.h that has a structure with two ints:

```
typedef struct {   
    int pid;
    int maxClientes;
    int maxMedicos;
} Balcao;
```

and i have another file called balcao.c with the following code:

```
Balcao b;
b.pid = getpid();
```

I go to the terminal and insert

"Export maxClientes=20"

"Export maxMedicos=50"

"./balcao.0" (after having it compiled through gcc -o)

but when i try to print the variables it just prints out 0.

How do i capture the values from export and save them in file ?

Comment: [man getenv](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)

Comment: @EugeneSh. so i have to do   int *getenv(const int *maxClientes); in the structure, is that it ?

Comment: @MauroAbrantes, no, you don't have to *declare* `getenv`. You have to *call* it and assign the results to something. Oh, and `getenv` returns a string, in your case you probably also want to convert the result to an `int`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yes, it does ! But with eugene and hals comments, i figured it out !